# Multi-threaded environment, other threads never get access to critical section

Tags: c++, multithreading, critical-section

Right now I am stuck, here is what I'm trying to do:

- Create 3 threads:
- These 3 threads will access a shared global resource (a vector)

At a certain point in the function (that all threads will call), there will be a Sleep(time) function, which makes the thread sleep, the function does not return. This is where I want another thread - thread 2, to access and use the function, modifying the global variable, until it sleeps, so thread 3 can access the function, ect...

The "critical section" function which accesses the global variable has an unspecified access time, it is never the same.

Initially, in main I call

```
    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);
```

What I attempted was, when this function is called, I immediately call

```
EnterCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);
```

I then modify global variables, ect, then before the Sleep(time) I call

```
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_stCriticalSection);
```

Problem with this is, the other threads don't EVER get access to the function, even though I leave it.
Is there a way for my other threads to continuously, or even every 5 seconds, get access to the critical section? Could my implementation be better?

So here's what I have now

```
void function() // all our threads will access this
{
   EnterCriticalSection(&obj)
   // manipulate global data
   LeaveCriticalSection(&obj)
   Sleep(long time) // another thread SHOULD NOW have access to this section!
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any possibility that a process is failing in the "// manipulate global data" section?

If so, then LeaveCriticalSection(&obj) would never be called.

Have you tried putting debug logs right before LeaveCriticalSection(&obj)?

Comment: All control paths go to the LeaveCriticalSection(&obj)
Even if something fails inside the critical section, the thread still sleeps, eventually... 
I'll attempt to put debug logs after it, that's a good idea.

Comment: Your use of the critical section is the correct way to do it. It is possible the Sleep calls are causing a problem (deadlock) if other threads are waiting for the sleeping thread. The usual cause of such deadlocks is using SendMessage to a window created in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's more errorprone to use scoped-helpers which help you agains situation like 'some exception occurs after EnterCriticalSection() and before LeaveCriticalSection() so that LeaveCriticalSection() really never happens'.

You could do some wrapper (see above) around CS with some trace.

Also, I assume that it would be easy to collect the application dump and see via WinDbg current thread state & cs state.